# GraphDB - very slow sparql query with two connections

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

My database has information about documents, where each document has a category, e.g.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX: <http://example.com>

:doc1 :hasCategory :category1 .
:category1 rdfs:label "Law" .
```

There are about 100k statements like this.

Running a simple query to get counts of documents per category:

```
SELECT ?category (count(distinct ?doc) as ?count) WHERE {
    ?doc :hasCategory ?category .
} GROUP BY ?category
```

takes about 0.1s to run.

But to return the category labels as well:

```
SELECT ?category ?label (count(distinct ?doc) as ?count) WHERE {
            ?doc :hasCategory ?category .
            ?category rdfs:label ?label .
} GROUP BY ?category ?label
```

this query takes more than 7s to run.

Why would the difference be so large, and is there a more optimised query I can use to get the labels?

Comment: You can check and compare the [query plans](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/explain-plan.html) of both queries. Do you really need to group by label in each category? If there is only a single label per category, try `SELECT ?category (sample(?label) as ?l) (count(distinct ?doc) as ?count) WHERE { ...} GROUP BY ?category`

Comment: The estimated number of iterations is 39926 for both queries. `sample` reduced the time taken by a second, but it's still about 6s

Comment: Actually it's 39926 for the first query and 39926.4551683254 for the second query.

Comment: The number of unique objects for the first statement `?doc :hasCategory ?category .` is only 133 . I would have imagined that it only has to find labels for 133 categories

Answer (score 3):

I found I can get the desired result in 0.2s with the following query:

```
SELECT ?category (sample(?lbl) as ?label) ?count WHERE {
    ?category rdfs:label ?lbl .
    {
        SELECT ?category (count(distinct ?doc) as ?count) WHERE {
            ?doc :hasCategory ?category .
        } GROUP BY ?category 
    }
} GROUP BY ?category ?count
```

But I don't really understand why it's more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

GraphDB versions before 8.6 release implement the GROUP BY operation with a naive LinkedHashMap, where the hash key is composed of all elements part of the projection. To calculate the hashcode the engine will translate the internal identifier to a RDF value. If the strings are longer, they will be read from an external collection resulting an extra disk operation and additional CPU to calculate the hashcode.

The only way to optimise the query is to switch to GraphDB 8.6 (currently it's a late release candidate), which implements a more optimised aggregate algorithm or reduce the GROUP BY projection like you did in your answer.